# Treatment for a palm tree recovering from frost damage

Tags: palm, frost

Our palm tree got hit by the frost earlier this year and lost all its leaves.  It has now started to regrow but mainly from the base, the top part of the tree is dead.

Should I prune these leaves and should I also remove the top part that is dead? My thinking is that if I remove the dead part it will start growing from the top again.

[image: A photograph of the palm tree, showing growth at the base and a couple of places part way up the trunk]

Comment: Yes, the topmost growth will take over. But not beautifully. Better to cut close the ground - sorry - and leave exactly one new tree.

Comment: Best thing is adequate watering and well drained soil. CIrcumstance most people who try palms in their properties. Palms ideal fertilizer has an NPK ratio of 3-1-3 and micronutrients iron, copper, zinc.

Comment: What sort of palm is it

Answer (score 0):

It's best to prune/chop off the main trunk, almost to the base, without damaging the new growth.  If you dont, the rot could affect the rest of the tree.  Chop it at an angle so water drains off.

As a precaution, I would keep 2 or 3 shoots and prune the rest.  In 6-12 mths time, remove the weakest looking one.  And repeat again in 6-12 mths time.